# Spring MVC: ResponseBodyAdvice doesn't get called for null response from controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring boot REST API app. I have a use-case to add some common parameters to all API responses such as `time` and `clientId`. To achieve this, I am using a `ResponseBodyAdvice` to manipulate the output of controllers. However, if a controller returns `null`, the `ResponseBodyAdvice` doesn't get called. I have verified this by adding logs and breakpoints.

My question is how do i overcome this behavior? Basically for cases when a controller returns `null` such a when no data exists, I still want my API output to contain the common fields.

This is my expected output for API `GET /users/{userId}` when there is no user for the given id.

```
{
   "time": "2018-11-10 23:00:00",
   "clientId": "MyClient",
   "data": null
}
```

However as my ResponseBodyAdvice is not executing, I am getting no output only `200` with other headers.

Here is the code of my ResponseBodyAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice("com.tl.core.controller")
public class TLResponseAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

@Override
public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    System.out.println("::RBA:: supports");
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
        Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request,
        ServerHttpResponse response) {
    System.out.println("::RBA:: beforebodywrite1 " + body);
    if(returnType.getMethod().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("handleControllerException")) {
        return body;
    }
    System.out.println("::RBA:: beforebodywrite2");
    final RestResponse<Object> output = new RestResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    output.setData(body);
    // set common fields here.
    ...
    return output;
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseBody
public TLResponseEntity<Object> handleControllerException(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex) {
    final RestResponse<Object> output = new RestResponse<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    // set common fields here
    ...
    final TLResponseEntity<Object> finaloutput = new TLResponseEntity<>(output);
    return finaloutput;
}
```

}

Comment: Just a tweak, you can try with empty string from controller end and set null (if you really need null ). Let me know if `beforeBodyWrite` invoked properly.

Comment: Not possible to do this. The response type of controller is not String. I cannot return empty string from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return as follows from your controller in order to execute the ResponseBodyAdvice in case of NULL response.

```
new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Then once your ResponseBodyAdvice is executed you can restructure your response.

Basically your controller should not just return NULL but the ResponseEntity with NULL data would force required behaviour for your case.

Comment: Any reason why responseBodyAdvice doesn't work with null?

Comment: @Adi can you share your code which is finally returning NULL ? How you prepare your responseBodyAdvice?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body,
                                  @NotNull MethodParameter returnType,
                                  @NotNull MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  @NotNull Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  @NotNull ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  @NotNull ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (body == null) {
            if (returnType.getMethod().getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                return JsonUtils.toString(new RestResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
            }
            return new RestResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        }
        if (body instanceof RestResponse) {
            return body;
        }
        if (body instanceof String) {
            final RestResponse<Object> output = JsonUtils.toString(GlobalResponse.successResult(body));
        }
        final RestResponse<Object> output = new RestResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        output.setData(body);
        // set common fields here.
         ...
        return output;
    }
```

controller rest function returns value type should not be 'Object'
when return 'Object' type, return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);